# One CloudFront, one S3 bucket to serve many react apps using Lambda@Edge

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

The company I work at wants to serve multiple react websites using a single S3 bucket and Cloudfront distribution as there is a limit to the number of buckets AWS allows. The base file structure we want to have has three folders at the root of the bucket (i.e. dev, prod, and sandbox), and each has its corresponding react project.

From the Cloudfront distribution, I send the Host header to know which environment and bucket should be served. I catch that in a Lambda@Edge function and route to the corresponding bucket, which works up to that point. The Lambda@Edge function gets the index.html file correctly but cannot serve all the other files in the folder. This results in just getting a blank white screen with a couple of errors in the console: `The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css` and `Loaded file has not a valid JavaScript MIME type`.

The Lambda@Edge function I use is the following:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    // Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge 
    var cf = event.Records[0].cf;
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const origin = request.origin;
    const domain = request.headers.host[0].value;

    if (domain.includes("dev")) {
        request.uri = "/dev-test/index.html"
    } else if (domain.includes("sandbox") {
        request.uri = "/sandbox-test/index.html";
    } else {
        request.uri = "/prod-test/index.html";
    }
    request.headers.host[0].value = origin.s3.domainName

    // Return to CloudFront
    return callback(null, request);
}
```

That function extracts the domain from the Host header, sets the URI accordingly, and changes the Host header to the S3 domain name to avoid getting a permissions error. I have also tried changing the S3 path as well as the URI, changing only the path instead of the URI but nothing seems to work. I do not know if I should be setting/changing something else in the request or I should change the settings/permissions in my S3 bucket and/or Cloudfront distribution.

By the way, I am testing this with a basic React JS app, I only ran `npx create-react-app my-app` then built it and uploaded everything in the build folder to the S3 bucket folders.

Thank you very much in advance for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your requests coming back with a 200 OK status and the correct content — you just see a blank screen with that console error? If that's the case, then the issue is that you need to set the mime type on the CSS file in order for your browser to display it. Some browsers like Chrome won't serve a CSS file without the text/css Content-Type header.

You have three ways to set it:

1. Add it as metadata to each CSS file in your S3 bucket
2. Use a Lambda@Edge origin response function to dynamically set the Content-Type header based on the file extension.
3. Create a new cache behavior with a path pattern of `*.css` and attach a [Response Header Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/understanding-response-headers-policies.html#understanding-response-headers-policies-custom) that sets the Content-Type of text/css as a custom header with Origin Override checked (this is free to use, and will perform faster than Lambda@Edge as it's a native feature)

Option 1 is the simplest if you add it as part of your upload workflow. Otherwise would recommend option 3.